# Ajax content, and noscript alternative- best practice?

Tags: ajax, seo, noscript

I have a content listings page on a site I'm developing that uses ajax to pull items based on filtering picked by the user. (filter by date/ tag/ genre etc)

In order for the page to work for crawlbots and non-javascript users I have a standard listing of content as well, hidden, but with a noscript tag in the header making it display:block
(Have been told this is okay in html5).

Trouble is- the site is doing everything twice now- loading the content via ajax as well as the alternative, only to be hidden with CSS.

I know for sure this isn't best practice, but I'm struggling to think of a solution where the content only loads once. Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could display them always with CSS, and then hide them with JS. (Without the use of noscript)